# how to inject bean into own implementation SimpleJpaRepository

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Follow this tutorial [Extending the JPA specification executor](http://jeroenbellen.ghost.io/spring-data-extending-the-jpa-specification-executor/) i wrote my own implementation of `JpaRepository<T, ID>`:

```
public class SimpleFilterableJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements
        FilterExecutor<T> {

    //How to inject object here
    @Autowired
    public JpaFilterSpecificationResolver specificationResolver;

    public SimpleFilterableJpaRepository(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
       super(entityInformation, entityManager);

    }

    public SimpleFilterableJpaRepository(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);

    }

..........

}
```

I have no idea how to deliver `JpaFilterSpecificationResolver` ? Any idea
This class have two constructor. First constructor is called in `org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport` and second is using by `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean`.

So for second one there is no problem to deliver 'specificationResolver'? but first is called via proxy :/

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Alec yes i solve that problem

Comment: How? I have similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868945/autowired-does-not-work-in-simplejparepository-extension