# @Autowired does not work in SimpleJpaRepository extension

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

When trying to override `SimpleJpaRepository`, adding other beans via `@Autowired` does not work. How can beans be injected in this case? Here is an implementation:

```
public class BaseDAO<T, ID extends Serializable>
             extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>
             implements IDAO<T, ID> {
  @Autowired
  private SomeBean someBean; // NULL!
}
```

Comment: Similar question stays unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528234/how-to-inject-bean-into-own-implementation-simplejparepository

Comment: I was the one who edited out the unnecessary code from the question. I also clarified in the comments that the extra code has no bearing on the problem or its solution. If you felt that the edit was unnecessary, feel free to revert to your original question. Check my answer below to see why all the additional code is not necessary to get to a solution and see if the proposed solution works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instances of `BaseDAO` are not Spring-managed beans in themselves and therefore autowiring through `@Autowired` will not work out-of-the-box. Dependencies therefore need to be injected into `BaseDAO` instances.

---

> **Step 1**: Have a Spring `ApplicationContext` available somewhere

```
@Component
class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {
  private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

  public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
    CONTEXT = context;
  }

  public static ApplicationContext getContext() { return CONTEXT; }
}
```

This will be required to autowire the dependencies for the custom repository implementation at the time of repository creation.

> **Step 2**: Extend `SimpleJpaRepository`

```
class BaseDAO<T, ID extends Serializable>
      extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> {
  @Autowired
  private Dependency dependency;
}
```

> **Step 3**: Autowire dependencies through a `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean`

```
class ExtendedJPARepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, T, ID extends Serializable>
      extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, ID> {
  private static class ExtendedJPARepositoryFactory<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {
    public ExtendedJPARepositoryFactory(final EntityManager entityManager) {
      super(entityManager);
    }

    protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(final RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
      return isQueryDslExecutor(metadata.getRepositoryInterface())
             ? QueryDSLJPARepository.class
             // Let your implementation be used instead of SimpleJpaRepository.
             : BaseDAO.class;
    }

    protected <T, ID extends Serializable> SimpleJpaRepository<?, ?> getTargetRepository(
        RepositoryInformation information, EntityManager entityManager) {
      // Let the base class create the repository.
      final SimpleJpaRepository<?, ?> repository = super.getTargetRepository(information, entityManager);

      // Autowire dependencies, as needed.
      SpringContext.getContext()
                   .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
                   .autowireBean(repository);

      // Return the fully set up repository.
      return repository;
    }
  }

  protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
    return new ExtendedJPARepositoryFactory(entityManager);
  }
}
```

> **Step 4a**: Configure Spring Data JPA to use your factory bean (XML configuration)

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="org.example.jpa"
                  factory-class="org.example.jpa.ExtendedJPARepositoryFactoryBean"/>
```

> **Step 4b**: Configure Spring Data JPA to use your factory bean (Java configuration)

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = ExtendedJPARepositoryFactoryBean.class)
```

Comment: Actually i was thinking about this solution, but i was also wondering, why spring data creators did not take into account, that additional behavior could be needed. Solution works perfectly, but it still looks like a workaround. I accept it, anyway

Answer (score -2):

In order to let Spring know that it needs to inject something inside your DAO you need to annotate it with @Component.

You can read more about this here: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html.

Comment: Yes, i know the fundamentals :) But in this specific case if it is annotated with @Component - i get immediately 

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.model.dao.BaseDAO required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation' that could not be found.

And app does not start, obviously